# scala unpack tuple into case class arguments and additional zip two sequences

Tags: scala, zip, unpack

I want to transform `Seq[String, Seq[Char]]` into `Seq[UnpackedObject]` but don't know how to unpack tuple of two Chars (A, B) to separate case class arguments.

I want to basically create s3 out of s1 and s2 such that:

```
Seq(("aaa", "A", B"), ("bbb", "B", C"), ("ccc", "C", "D"), ("ddd", "D", "D"))
```

hence I am trying to use case class but:

- problem 1: unpacking tuple into two arguments;
- problem 2: last element with "D", "D" <-- I don't know how to solve it.

```
val s1 = Seq("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
val s2 = ('A' to 'D').sliding(2).toSeq
val pairs = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => UnpackedObject(a, b) }
    
case class UnpackedObject(a: String, b: Char, c: Char)
```

this above is my code so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zipped` function expects `Seq` with the same length but you passed `s2` of length 3 and `s1` length is 4. You need to add one element into `s2` to get `s3`:

```scala
val s1 = Seq("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd") 
val s2 = ('A' to 'D').sliding(2).toSeq :+ Seq('D', 'D')
// ('A' to 'D').sliding(2) will return just 
// Seq(Seq('A', 'B'), Seq('B', 'C'), Seq('C', 'D'))
val pairs = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => (a, b.head, b.last) }
// will return Seq((aaa,A,B), (bbb,B,C), (ccc,C,D), (ddd,D,D))
```

if you need to create `UnpackedObject`, you can do it just call `tupled` `apply` function of case class:

```scala
val objects = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => (a, b.head, b.last) }
  .map((UnpackedObject.apply _).tupled)
// will return 
// Seq(
//   UnpackedObject(aaa,A,B), UnpackedObject(bbb,B,C), 
//   UnpackedObject(ccc,C,D), UnpackedObject(ddd,D,D))
```

Comment: I think the final `map` function could simply be `UnpackedObject.tupled`.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is not tuple but rather a indexed sequence, so:

```
val pairs = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => UnpackedObject(a, b(0), b(1)) }
```

or

```
val pairs = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => UnpackedObject(a, b.head, b.last) }
```

As for 2nd point and using tuples you can do:

```scala
val s1 = Seq("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
val s2 = ('A' to 'D').zip(('B' to 'D')) :+ ('D', 'D')
val pairs = (s1, s2).zipped.map { case (a, b) => UnpackedObject(a, b._1, b._2) }
```